# What is a good way to verify if a passport photo meets the official requirements (In a Angular application)

Tags: angular, photo

I am building an Angular application. In one part of the application, people can upload their official ID photos. This photo must fit some (official) requirements provided by the government. Does anyone have recommendations on how to check Whether a photo meets these requirements or not.

I am looking around for maybe a good (API) service or library that makes this specific use case happen, but I have not found a good solution so far. Recommendations or tips are welcome!

Best case scenario:

1. The user uploads their passport photo
2. The system checks the photo
3. The system approves the photo if the official requirements are met, or gives feedback on what is wrong with the photo.

Comment: Recommendations are _not_ welcome; questions soliciting them are off topic per the [help]. I'd recommend taking the [tour] and reading [ask].

Answer (score 0):

When you need to check whether a passport photo meets official requirements, especially in the context of web development or an Angular application, there are usually a few key factors to consider. These include the size of the photo, background color, visibility of facial features, and any special guidelines provided by the passport issuing authority.

One effective approach could be to integrate an API that specializes in image analysis and can check images against passport photo standards. This would automate the process of checking whether the photo meets the necessary criteria, such as size, resolution, background color, and placement of facial features.

There are neural network-based services that offer country-specific processing - like this one https://photogov.com/documents/sg-passport-online-photo/.

In your Angular application, you can create a service that uses such resources to validate photos uploaded by users. This would not only simplify the process, but also ensure that the photos meet the requirements of the country for which the passport is being issued.